# After float: left and float: right clear: both?

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question. I created a navigation bar with this html-code:

```html
<!-- Header and searchbar -->
<header>
    <div class="header">

        <div class="left">  
                <a href="">
                <img id="logo" src="pictures/airbnb2.png" alt="Airbnb Logo"> 
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <ul class="right navbar">
                <li><a href="">Gastgeber werden</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hilfe</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Registrieren</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Log-in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

So my question is how to clear this code correctly? Do i have to do clear: right in the next div or clear: both? I floated left (class left) first and afterwards right (class right).

Thanks ;)

Comment: You can clear: right on the next item you add and it will appear under the header, clear: left puts the next item under the image. Since clear: both is a combination of the two, clear: right will predominate in this case

Comment: @PhobosFerro does it make any difference if i only use clear:right?

Comment: It doesn't, clear: both works the same as clear: right in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `clear:left` Is a keyword indicating that the element is moved down to clear past left floats.

Since you have a `float: right` right after `float: left`, if you only use `clear: right` your element will appear under the header, because you cleared the last floating object.

If you use `clear: left`, you will clear the left floating element, but not the right one, so the next elements will appear under the left floating one.

So in this case, if you use `clear: both`, you would be doing the same as doing `clear: right`.

`clear: both` is used so no floating elements are on either side of the new element, which is not what you're doing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear